# How do @IBInspectable properties aggregate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, interface-builder, custom-controls

This is a 3rd library custom control:

[image: custom control in IB]

However, my custom control puts all properties together. I wonder how to add separators among `@IBInspectable` properties to show in interface builder?

Comment: As far as I know you don't have any control over how IB presents inspectable properties.